# Enable Terminal plugin in Sublime Text

Tags: plugins, sublime-text

Is it possible to enable terminal plugin into Sublime Text editor, similar to Kate?

Answer (score 0):

Try `glue` in sublime text editor

Kindly find the below article for procedure in details:

http://sweetme.at/2014/04/07/glue-a-terminal-for-sublime-text/

#### Install with Git

1. Open your Packages directory with the Sublime Text menu items Preferences > Browse Packages.
2. Then git clone the Glue repository as a new directory named ‘Glue’ in your Packages directory with the following command:

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/chrissimpkins/glue.git "Glue"
   ```

#### Install with Package Control

1. In menus Tools > Command Palette 
   2.type `install` in the text entry field.
2. Select the option Package Control - Install Package.
3. type ‘glue’ in the text input box and select the ‘Glue’ plugin option that is displayed in the Command Palette.

The install automatically takes place.

You will see a confirmation in the status bar at the bottom of the editor window.

Comment: Essential parts appear to have been added.